# How can I specify a configuration file in ArangoDB docker image?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, arangodb

I'm trying to spin up an ArangoDB server via docker compose.

It all works out fine with default configuration, but I'm struggling to make the server in the container pick up a custom configuration file with [minimal setup](https://www.arangodb.com/2019/03/small-steps-reduce-arangodb-resource-footprint/)

I've tried with overriding the startup sequence with the following:

```yaml
command: >
    arangod --configuration /arango.conf
```

I've checked and the file is present in the container, but when I check the configuration file via [query through arangoshell](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/administration-configuration.html#fetch-current-configuration-options) it still references the default settings and the `arangod.conf` file placed in the `/tmp` folder.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--config /tmp/arangod.conf` is hardcoded in `docker-entrypoint.sh` [at line 185](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb-docker/blob/official/alpine/3.7.5/docker-entrypoint.sh#L185)

it is also overwritten upon every start of container with `/etc/arangodb3/arangod.conf` [at line 42](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb-docker/blob/official/alpine/3.7.5/docker-entrypoint.sh#L42)

so to run arangod with your `custom.conf` file you need map it as volume to `/etc/arangodb3/arangod.conf`

via docker compose

```yaml
volumes:
  /custom.conf:/etc/arangodb3/arangod.conf
```

via docker cli

```
-v /custom.conf:/etc/arangodb3/arangod.conf
```

---

UPDATE: as per comments

`custom.conf` have to contain defaults from `/etc/arangodb3/arangod.conf`

easiest way is to save default config to `custom.conf` via docker cli and add/update options in that file

```sh
docker run --rm arangodb/arangodb:3.7.5 sh -c 'cat /etc/arangodb3/arangod.conf' > custom.conf
```

it gonna be also required to track updates of default options in `/etc/arangodb3/arangod.conf` in new versions of ArangoDB and reflect them in your `custom.conf`

Comment: Your solution is right, so I marked it as correct answer. However this has caused additional issues: I thought the config file would override arangodb's default configurations, but apparently the startup procedure expects every necessary configuration in the file, there's no hard-coded default and the container fails to run every time asking for additional properties. Do you have any suggestion on how to simply override specific parameters in the startup phase?

Comment: default config is `/etc/arangodb3/arangod.conf`, so you need to base your config on it because you're overriding it. you can get it via `docker run --rm arangodb/arangodb:3.7.5 sh -c 'cat /etc/arangodb3/arangod.conf' > custom.conf`

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a try