# Upgrade Arangodb - how to add a command line flag when running in Docker?

Tags: docker, google-compute-engine, arangodb

We deployed an `arangodb` docker instance on google compute engine, about 2 years ago.

It always worked fine and was never restarted until now.  The `arangodb` was upgraded, but I can not upgrade the database. This is de compute engine log:

```
**A 2021-06-14T13:56:39.353155517Z 2021-06-14T13:56:39Z [1] ERROR [3bc7f] {startup} Database directory version (30503) is lower than current version (30711).
A 2021-06-14T13:56:39.353253420Z 2021-06-14T13:56:39Z [1] ERROR [ebca0] {startup} ----------------------------------------------------------------------
A 2021-06-14T13:56:39.353343821Z 2021-06-14T13:56:39Z [1] ERROR [24e3c] {startup} It seems like you have upgraded the ArangoDB binary.
A 2021-06-14T13:56:39.353429097Z 2021-06-14T13:56:39Z [1] ERROR [8bcec] {startup} If this is what you wanted to do, please restart with the
A 2021-06-14T13:56:39.353503511Z 2021-06-14T13:56:39Z [1] ERROR [b0360] {startup}   --database.auto-upgrade true
A 2021-06-14T13:56:39.353588233Z 2021-06-14T13:56:39Z [1] ERROR [13414] {startup} option to upgrade the data in the database directory.
A 2021-06-14T13:56:39.353662855Z 2021-06-14T13:56:39Z [1] ERROR [24bd1] {startup} ----------------------------------------------------------------------'
A 2021-06-14T13:56:39.353744994Z 2021-06-14T13:56:39Z [1] ERROR [1c156] Database 'DATMNG' needs upgrade. Please start the server with --database.auto-upgrade
A 2021-06-14T13:56:39.353875354Z 2021-06-14T13:56:39Z [1] FATAL [2eb08] Database 'DATMNG' upgrade failed (bad parameter). Please inspect the logs from the upgrade procedure and try starting the server again.
A 2021-06-14T13:56:39.503654Z time="2021-06-14T13:56:39.502998769Z" level=info msg="ignoring event" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete" 
A 2021-06-14T13:56:39.504312Z 2021-06-14T13:56:39.503105201Z container die 6ae973a8db5b45cf5057d3f26f9610aa8482c9132d5ff992b06f604a8ac72c22 (exitCode=1, image=aran*godb/arangodb, name=klt-arangodb-votd)*
```

I can not add that `--database.auto-upgrade true` anywhere in compute engine (I tried in the environment variables section in the compute engine, but didn't seem to catch on).

I am able to login on the Microserver where the docker container is installed, but the container stops working almost immediately after startup, so I can not shell to a prompt to do the upgrade manually.

I can start the container with:

```
docker run -ti -u root --entrypoint=sh image_id_or_name -s
```

But the config or changes are not retained here. Any insights or suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to know, what volumes or paths are mapped on instance created by compute engine, it's under [`Advanced container options`](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/configuring-options-to-run-containers#mounting_a_host_directory_as_a_data_volume)

in terminal you can use https://github.com/nexdrew/rekcod, run following command, change `<container>` to id/name of your initial instance

```sh
docker run --rm -i -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock nexdrew/rekcod <container>
```

in output you should get something like

```sh
docker run --name arangodb --runtime runc -v arangodb--3.7:/var/lib/arangodb3 -v arangodb-apps--3.7:/var/lib/arangodb3-apps -p 8529:8529/tcp --restart no -h 0e989039f8c8 --expose 8529/tcp -e 'ARANGO_NO_AUTH=1' -e 'PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin' -e 'GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW=1' -d --entrypoint "/entrypoint.sh" arangodb/arangodb:3.7.5 'arangod'
```

`-v` arguments are those you'll need to add when you run backup and upgrade

---

before upgrade create backup with following command, if you have default config, then you need backup `/var/lib/arangodb3`, change `<volume>` to volume/path according to output in previous step

```sh
docker run --rm -v /tmp:/backup -v <volume>:/var/lib/arangodb3 busybox tar -zcvf /backup/arangodb3.tar.gz /var/lib/arangodb3
```

that gonna create data backup `/tmp/arangodb3.tar.gz` on your host machine, keep that.

if you'll need restore you can run

```sh
docker run --rm -v <volume>:/var/lib/arangodb3 -v /tmp:/backup busybox tar -xzvf /backup/arangodb3.tar.gz var/lib/arangodb3
```

---

WARNING: as per [General Upgrade Information / Upgrade Paths](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/upgrading-general-info.html#upgrade-paths)

you'll need to upgrade your `3.5.3` in multiple steps

1. first to `3.5.7`
2. second to `3.6.13`
3. last to `3.7.11`

to upgrade run following command, change `<volume>` to volume/path according to output in previous step, change `<arango-image>` to target arangodb image version

```sh
docker run -v <volume>:/var/lib/arangodb3 <arango-image> arangod --database.auto-upgrade=true
```

---

then start arangodb in compute engine

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed manual.
When running rekcod we get this output:
docker run --expose 8529/tcp -e 'PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin' -e 'GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW=1' -d --entrypoint "/entrypoint.sh" sha256:<long key> 'arangod'

Comment: I see that the DB files are under /var/lib/arangodb on the docker server (I can see files like ENGINE, SERVER, ... engine-rocksdb etc.....) but don't know the commandline to start the container manually to start a manual upgrade.  Thank you again!

Comment: make backup of  `/var/lib/arangodb` before anything else, then use `/var/lib/arangodb` in place of <volume> in last command `docker run -v <volume>:/var/lib/arangodb3 <arango-image> arangod --database.auto-upgrade=true`, that should work

Comment: And that did the trick, thank you for your help!!!  If I change the running config to also listen to an ssl port, I need to make a new copy of the image ? Or can I do this with a parameter in Environment variables in the advanced settings in the vm instance on google ?  Thank you again!

Comment: I'm not sure about config via env vars, but for config file you can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65481623/how-can-i-specify-a-configuration-file-in-arangodb-docker-image/65486102#65486102. also mark please answer as solution as per https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers . Thanks